# Maximum of conditional expectation

Tags: statistics, financial-economics

I have a statistics question for the insider problem in the Kyle (1985) model:

How does one go from

$\max\limits_{X} E[(v-\bar{v}-\lambda(X+u))X|v]$

to

$\max\limits_{X} (v-\bar{v}-\lambda X)X$ ?

Comment: Probably because $E(u \mid v )=0$.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks.